# how can we search a number from multiple rows/columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns. 3rd column is in sorted way which is numbers from 1 to 7.
2nd and 3rd column ares number between 0 to 9. 
I want to search numbers in 3rd column between A1 to B7. 
i have used the below formula to calculate the same and i am getting correct.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:A,1,FALSE)),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,B:B,1,FALSE)),"Not found","Found"),"Found")
```

However when am using full block(A1:B7) it is not working.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A$1:$B$7,1,FALSE)),"Not found","Found")
```

Considering N number of columns, how can we achieve the same.

```
2   7   1   Found
4   5   2   Found
6   4   3   Found
7   2   4   Found
2   1   5   Not found
3   9   6   Found
1   2   7   Found
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Can you share how can we search using that index formula if you know any?

Comment: Have you tried COUNTIF?

Comment: no.. not yet.. will try from myside.

Comment: tried =COUNTIF($A$1:$B$7, C1) this. it is giving correct. onlything required to reciprocate it to found or not found..

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$7, C1)>0,"FOUND",IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$7, C1)=0,"NOT FOUND"))

Comment: That works, but you don't need to list the COUNTIF twice =IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$B$7, C1) >0,"found","not found")